# ERROR: IOError: closed stream in chef Knife

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, knife, cookbook

I am trying to setup SAS office analytics using chef on redhat machine. The problem is that the script that installs SAS components takes too much time like more than an hour. I run the cookbook recipe using knife bootstrap command. It runs for few minutes and then it throws closed stream error.

Following is the command that I am using to bootstrap.

```
knife bootstrap xx.xxx.xx.xxx --ssh-user ec2-user -i sec.pem --bootstrap-version 12.4.3 --sudo  -VVV --use-sudo-password --node-name aws1-node --run-list recipe['SAS::oa'] -y
```

Following are the last few lines of the output.

```
* execute[setup for sas] action run[2018-01-21T12:52:10-05:00] INFO: Processing execute[setup for sas] action run (SAS::oa line 72)
[2018-01-21T12:52:10-05:00] DEBUG: Providers for generic execute resource enabled on node include: [Chef::Provider::Execute]
[2018-01-21T12:52:10-05:00] DEBUG: Provider for action run on resource execute[setup for sas] is Chef::Provider::Execute
DEBUG: received packet nr 1872 type 94 len 28
INFO: channel_data: 0 2b
DEBUG: received packet nr 1873 type 94 len 60
INFO: channel_data: 0 40b
Preparing the SAS Deployment Wizard...
DEBUG: read 84 bytes
DEBUG: received packet nr 1874 type 94 len 60
INFO: channel_data: 0 40b
Launching the SAS Deployment Wizard...
DEBUG: read 0 bytes
ERROR: IOError: closed stream
```

Following the code block that got stuck.

```
#run install setup from response file
execute "setup for sas" do
  user "root"
  cwd "/home/sas"
  command "su sas -c 'bash /sas/sasdepot/SAS_Software_Depot/setup.sh -quiet -responsefile /sas/response_files/office_analytics_install.properties'"
end
```

Can someone please suggest me how can I avoid this close stream error?

thanks

Comment: Sorry, but thought few users may not use both the platform.

Comment: script execution for more than 1hr is weird. But have to tried 1/ executing the script manually to check if it really take that long?  2/ Can try by increasing the timeout for the execute resource. The default is 60mins. https://docs.chef.io/resource_execute.html